# angular service method is not a function prod build

Tags: angular

I try to get my angular app running in prod mode to check if all is fine.

The app uses swapi API to get actors which is working fine, except in prod build, then I get the following error

> this.dataService.getActors is not a function

and this is the method to get all Actors:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { IActor } from '../interfaces/Actor';

import { ErrorService } from './error.service';


/**
 * SWAPI Data Service to get all from their API we need
 */

@Injectable()

export class DataService {

  /**
* we need the http client here to get API data
*/

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public error: ErrorService) { }

  /**
 * Method to get all Actors
 */

  getActors(): Observable<IActor[]> {
    return this.http.get<IActor[]>('//swapi.dev/api/people/')
      .map(data => {
        return data['results'];
      });
  }

  /**
* Method to get Actor details by their ID
*/

  getActorDetails(id: string): Observable<IActor[]> {
    return this.http.get<IActor[]>(`//swapi.dev/api/people/` + id + '/')
      .map(data => {
        return data['results'];
      });
  }

}
```

this is the call in my component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IActor } from '../../interfaces/Actor';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-actors',
  templateUrl: './actors-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actors-list.component.scss']
})
export class ActorsListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() actors: IActor[];

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private dataService: DataService) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getActors()
      .subscribe((data) => { this.actors = data; });
  }



}
```

Here are the whole files to check what's not right.
What am I missing here? Thank you!

Comment: I believe you are injecting the correct class of "dataService" in the constructor and your service (dataService) has the annotation "providedIn"... right? Can you share that part too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **providedIn:'root'** from your DataService and add **@Injectable()** as following. Also add your DataService into app.module.ts under providers array. Like, providers: [ DataService ]

```
import {}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
      // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem related to the code. The only thing, maybe, are the imports. In prod mode this can be a problem. Try change this

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';  // You are not using this
```

to this

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: thank you, did i need to reinstall rjxjs or compat for this? I cant import with import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Why not? Is there any specific error or something? Which version of rxjs are installed and how did you create your application? With angular cli?

Comment: Ive created the app with the cli and rxjs 6.6 and compat 6.6.3. If I use your map import then map gives me an error it is  unused but I use it in my data.service with  getActors(): Observable<IActor[]> {
    return this.http.get<IActor[]>('//swapi.dev/api/people/')
      .map(data => {
        return data['results'];
      });
  }.

Comment: I refactored now from map pipe(map) and it works, thanks a lot.